# Windows - Start a batch script in background and stop it once other tasks are done

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, batch-file

I have a Jenkins project that needs to run a batch script while it executes other commands. So the script would need to be run in background. I would also like to stop the background script once my other commands are done executing.

I started experimenting with the `START /B myscript.bat`, but couldn't find a way to stop the `myscript.bat` by its name. Is there an easy way to stop background batch processes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Is there an easy way to stop background batch processes?

Yes. You can use `taskkill`.

Example:

```
taskkill /f /fi "windowtitle eq Administrator: Command Prompt - myscript.bat"
```

---

#### Further Reading

- [An A-Z Index of the Windows CMD command line](http://ss64.com/nt/)
- [A categorized list of Windows CMD commands](https://ss64.com/nt/commands.html)
- [taskkill](http://ss64.com/nt/taskkill.html) - End one or more processes (by process id or image name).